# xlwings alternative on Linux

Tags: python, excel, linux, xlwings

I have a small Python script with the purpose of updating certain cells of an Excel sheet stored on Onedrive. In particular, the Excel workbook contains a price list in one sheet, a list of variables (e.g., currency exchange rate) that are to be updated automatically via Python in the second sheet, and a history of currency exchange rates in the 3rd (also to be edited via Python). I want to let a Raspberry Pi run and execute the script at regular hours and thereby update the field that contains the currency exchange rate from Rand to Euro and to insert the current value to a history of currency exchange rates.
The script should work without causing errors in case the Excel sheet is open on other devices etc (multiple users should be able to read and edit the file).
On Windows, I made it work like this:

```
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates
import xlwings as xw
from datetime import datetime

# get date and time
now = datetime.now()
current_date = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
# Get current Rand to Euro conversion rate
rates = CurrencyRates()
RtoEUR = rates.get_rate("ZAR", "EUR")
# edit workbook
exl_app = xw.App(visible = False)
wb = xw.Book("/mnt/usb/LELE_expenses.xlsx")
## update currency exch. rate
sht0 = wb.sheets["Auto_upd_vals"]
sht0.range("C2").value = RtoEUR
sht1 = wb.sheets["Hist"]
last = sht1.range("B" + str(wb.sheets[0].cells.last_cell.row)) \
    .end("up").row
## save current date, time and currency exch. rate
sht1.range("A" + str(last + 1)).value = current_date
sht1.range("B" + str(last + 1)).value = current_time
sht1.range("C" + str(last + 1)).value = RtoEUR
wb.save()
wb.close()
exl_app.quit()
```

Unfortunately, it is not possible to install `xlwings` on Raspbian. Are there any alternatives to make this happen?

**Errors so far:**

`pip3 install xlwings` results in "xlwings requires an installation of Excel and therefore only works on Windows and macOS..."
Running `export INSTALL_ON_LINUX=1` enables installation, but the module cannot be imported. Presumably because it still doesn't have Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, I guess this was easier than I expected:

```
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from datetime import datetime

# get date and time
now = datetime.now()
current_date = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
# Get current Rand to Euro conversion rate
rates = CurrencyRates()
RtoEUR = rates.get_rate("ZAR", "EUR")
# edit workbook
wb = load_workbook("/mnt/usb/LELE_expenses.xlsx")
## update currency exchange rate
sht0 = wb["Auto_upd_vals"]
sht0["C2"].value = RtoEUR
# append currency exchange rate history
sht1 = wb["Hist"]
sht1.append([current_date, current_time, RtoEUR])
wb.save("/mnt/usb/LELE_expenses.xlsx")
wb.close()
```

doesn't require Excel. I am not sure if it will cause any problems, though.

Comment: Hi, I was also facing this issue. Can you give an update on whether you had any problem afterwards by using openpyxl?

Comment: openpyxl works fine, I haven't had any issues so far. However, I had to schedule the automated changes for the Excel Workbook to some time at night since the way I update it is to download the current file from OneDrive, change it and re-upload it. This will overwrite any changes another user might have done in the meantime, since it is not like working in a shared document online as possible with Office apps