# XLWings Unable to Load a Workbook on Remote Instance

Tags: python, xlwings

XLwings works locally on my Windows machine, but if I try to run it remotely on a SageMaker instance (which I believe uses Linux under the hood) it doesn't work. What do I need to do to enable this?

Code is:

```
wb = xw.Book('my_excel_file.xlsx')
```

Which results in the following error:

```
XlwingsError: Your platform only supports the instantiation via xw.Book(json=...)
```

I'm planning on using XLwings to automatically run an excel model for me (update inputs, run model, save outputs) and I don't think this would be possible if converted to JSON - and I can't find anything in the docs to help me either. Appreciate the help!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hello brother I am not pro but I also have encountered this error, check sys.platform. mine is linux so it won't work
https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/installation.html
I am checking out this [xlwings alternative on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68771270/xlwings-alternative-on-linux)

hopefully it will help you

Comment: Although links to resources can be helpful, please make sure you explain the essence of the solution inside your answer. Also, avoid greetings and other introductory phrases. Just come to the essence immediately.